# Knockout add an item to an array conditionally

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

My application is MVC5.  Using Ajax I am getting the array from Database, works well.  However when I check if the value of specific item is not null and try to add it to the array it does not add it.  I am using the following:

```
if (result && result.ohaMed.length > 0) {
   for (var l = 0; l < result.ohaMed.length; l++) {
   self.ohaitems.push({ OhaTypeId: result.ohaMed[l].OhaTypeId, Name: result.ohaMed[l].Name});
     if (result.ohaMed[l].InfoURL != null) {
        if (self.ohaitems.indexOf(result.ohaMed[l].InfoURL) < 0) {
            self.ohaitems.push({ InfoURL: result.ohaMed[l].InfoURL });
        }
     };
   };
 };
```

If I add InfoURL as part of the first push it works.

Comment: You need to provide more details ... what is `result.ohaMed` array of observableArray? What is `self.ohaitems` ... I assume it is observableArray?

Comment: Yes it is an observableArray. The issue is when I am using if statement.